# mod_fcgid + Python + Apache 2.2 / RHEL 5 : output to error_log, not browser

Tags: apache-2.2, python, fastcgi, selinux, mod-fcgid

I'm trying to get a Django + [mod_fcgid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) setup working (mod_wsgi is tricky as I have a statically-linked Python. Don't ask.) While this was trivial on my Mac OS X development box, getting it running on the server has, so far, proven impossible.

With this configuration

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

FCGIDSocketPath run/mod_fcgid
FCGIDSharememPath run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm

ScriptAliasMatch  /apps/([^/]+)(/.*)? /var/www/apps/$1/apache/dispatch.fcgi$2

<DirectoryMatch ^/var/www/apps/([^/]+)/apache>
  SetHandler fcgid-script
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Options +ExecCGI
</DirectoryMatch>
```

and this example `dispatch.fcgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/lib/python2.5/site-packages/flup-1.0.2.egg')

def myapp(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['This is my hello world test!\n']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
    WSGIServer(myapp).run()
```

Browsing to my test page yields a 500 error and in my Apache error logs, I get:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 29

This is my hello world test!
[Wed Sep 30 11:09:18 2009] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/apps/test/apache/dispatch.fcgi(31043) exit(server exited), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 0
```

There's my output, looking great -- except in Apache's error log, not my browser window.

When I remove my `SetHandler` directive, the output goes right where I want it; obviously, it's running in ordinary CGI mode. That's not high-performing enough for my Django app, which gets 1-2 second page load times in that configuration.

So far, I have tried:

- [flup](http://trac.saddi.com/flup) 1.0.2, flup 1.0.3 development version, and a random fcgi.py written by flup's author
- threaded and prefork versions of my FastCGI server
- An RPM version of mod_fcgid and Apache's SVN version
- Python 2.4 and Python 2.5 (py2.4 isn't a realistic deployment option, but for testing...)
- AliasMatch / ScriptAliasMatch / mod_rewrite

Nothing seems to make any difference, except that using AliasMatch shows me the source, which is rather as I'd expected.

Again, this was absolutely trivial on Mac OS X. It Just Works with a comparable configuration.

Other than getting a better Python and using mod_wsgi (which is possible, if a pain), how do I make it work?

Comment: Having a statically linked Python is not an obstacle to using mod_wsgi, it just isn't recommended. It shouldn't though be used in that way however if also loading mod_python in same server. So, the need to use mod_python at same time is the real restriction if only static library for Python exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: Some SELinux policy. I'm not expert enough to diagnose it, but doing:

```
/usr/sbin/setenforce 0
```

makes everything work like a charm.